# how to create separate login for frontend and backend using cakephp 3.0 and session should be different?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to create a application where role will be different like (Admin, Partner, Student,Trainer), And I want to separate session/Auth for each role and login too. I do not want to login with **Users** table, even want to with student, trainer like that. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't  make things complex:**

Manage your login access from two tables:

***Roles:***

```
This should include all role types
```

***Users:***

```
This should include at least login information like username/email, password etc.
```

And obviously make relations like:

```
Users belongs to Roles , means each user has different role.
```

You can manage login separately according to their role ([see here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)). On doing so yo don't need to login them from different table.I bet that just make things complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, it help me lot.