# How to create multiple login catageory in Cakephp 3 through Cakedc

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

I want to create login for multiple category like someone is trying to login in shopping website, it may be a user or a merchant or n option. Each category should behave different. Users tables should be one but according to category the page redirect to different time-line. Please guide the proper way to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create separate login for frontend and backend using cakephp 3.0 and session should be different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928653/how-to-create-separate-login-for-frontend-and-backend-using-cakephp-3-0-and-sess)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate `Users` by adding `User Group` table.

You can follow the below instructions as an **example** to do it.

> **Create Table :** `user_groups` {`UserGroups`}

```
+---------+-----------+
|   id    | title     |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | user      |
|       2 | merchant  |
|       3 | others    |
+---------+-----------+
```

**Note:** Association `UserGroups` hasMany `Users`

> **Create Table :** `users` {`Users`}

```
+---------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
|   id    | user_group_id |   name           | password  |
+---------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
|       1 |             1 | Normal User 1    |           |
|       2 |             1 | Normal User 2    |           |
|       3 |             2 | Merchant User 1  |           |
|       3 |             2 | Merchant User 2  |           |
+---------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
```

**Note:** Association `Users` belongsTo `UserGroups`

Now you can Identify your `logged in user` by finding `UserGroups`. And you can redirect using `UserGroups.title`